# Android application with multiple games

Tags: java, android, cordova

As part of a university project, I am trying to build an Android app that basically only has one large dashboard/menu with multiple games that need to be launched when clicked. I found a similar article that explains how I could achieve this with activities here: https://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/build-dashboard-ui-for-android/ but the problem is that the "mini games" that need to be launched are separate projects by themselves. So I need advise as to how to make an app with all the game projects joined, and any advise is welcomed. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by 'separate projects'? Do they all have to be separate apps?

Comment: You should be able to create different modules that can exist in different repos. Then just include those modules in the Dashboard application

Comment: @Amin They have to be separate apps because they are cordova wrapped games, made in Construct2, unless there is another way, any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: Could you describe how you would want the end result's implementaion to behave and how this realtes to 'projects'. Do you want multiple seperate apps and one that just launches them? or also installes? Or do you want to package multiple apps into one big? To what extent is copying or reinitiallizeing projects/code acceptable?

Comment: @xr100chris thank you, it was helpful.

Comment: @angelsss you're welcome! Glad it helped!